# I got an Error in Encrypting the Private Key using ethers

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain, javascript, hardhat

```
const ethers = require ("ethers")
const fs = require ("fs-extra")
require ("dotenv").config()

async function main () {
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY)
  const encryptedJSonKey = await wallet.encrypt(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_PASS , process.env.PRIVATE_KEY)
  console.log(encryptedJSonKey)
}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Error: progressCb should be function
at scryptInit (E:\BlockchainForLife\Patrick\node_modules@noble\hashes\scrypt.js:110:15)
at scryptAsync (E:\BlockchainForLife\Patrick\node_modules@noble\hashes\scrypt.js:199:84)
at _scryptAsync (E:\BlockchainForLife\Patrick\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\crypto\scrypt.js:8:43)
at scrypt (E:\BlockchainForLife\Patrick\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\crypto\scrypt.js:55:42)
at encryptKeystoreJson (E:\BlockchainForLife\Patrick\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\wallet\json-keystore.js:291:45)
at Wallet.encrypt (E:\BlockchainForLife\Patrick\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\wallet\wallet.js:48:65)
at main (E:\BlockchainForLife\Patrick\encryptKey.js:7:41)
at Object. (E:\BlockchainForLife\Patrick\encryptKey.js:11:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/wallet/) of ethers wallet encrypt function.

```
wallet.encrypt(password: Uint8Array | string, progressCallback?: ProgressCallback) -> Promise<string>
```

> Resolves to a JSON Keystore Wallet encrypted with password.
> If progressCallback is specified, it will receive periodic updates as the encryption process progreses.

In your code example, you pass `process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_PASS` and `process.env.PRIVATE_KEY` as string parameters. Whereas, `encrypt` only takes one `string` or `Uint8Array` and an optional parameter of type `ProgressCallback`.

So the following should resolve your problem.

```
const ethers = require ("ethers")
const fs = require ("fs-extra")
require ("dotenv").config()

async function main () {
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY)
  const encryptedJSonKey = await wallet.encrypt(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_PASS)
  console.log(encryptedJSonKey)
}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

I just tested it with the following code for ethers version 6.3.0.

```
const ethers = require ("ethers")

async function main () {
  const wallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom()
  const jsonKeystoreWallet = await wallet.encrypt("password")
  console.log(jsonKeystoreWallet)
}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
require('dotenv').config();

async function main() {
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);

  const encryptedJsonKey = await wallet.encrypt(
    process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD
  );
  console.log(encryptedJsonKey);
  fs.writeFileSync('./.encryptedKey.json', encryptedJsonKey);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).